# Seeking free georeferenced databases

Tags: data-request, geospatial, data.gov, uses-of-open-data

Could you help me to find free georeferenced databases for study purpose?

For example, database with georeferenced data about soil chemestry (N-P-K, Calcium, Magnesium...), soil physics (Soil Density), electric conductivity, Cation Exchange Capacity (CEC) and other relevant information.

Comment: Are you looking for soil/chemistry data specifically, or would you also be interested in climate, population, animal habitat, etc, data? I assume you are familiar with naturalearthdata.com ?

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with that site, but I'll keep my eye on it. Thanks! I'm interested mainly in soil data for now, to make some interpolations and practice geoprocessing, as long as I'm a Agronomist undergrad. But if You know any kind of sites or databases that I can use, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this help?
https://data.isric.org/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/home

Comment: I've never seen this website before. Thanks! I think it will help.